# Highest Jump Boost

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm pretty sure the highest jump boost level is 94, and that if it's over this then it glitches and you cannot jump.

Can anyone confirm whether the highest jump boost level is 94, or can it go higher before glitching?

The command I am using to apply the effect is:

```
/effect @p 8 5 94
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand what you mean by "Can Anyone Confirm Its 94 Or Could It Go Higher" but I do not understand what you mean by "If Over You Glitch And Dont Jump".

Anyways,

> "The maximum level an effect can have is level ***255***. Like any other normal potion effect, the effect completely wears off at the end of its duration. Unlike normal potion effects, potions with levels above 127 do not cause particle effects."

From: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect

Hope that helps :P

Comment: After a certain effect amount, jump boost just doesn't work. This is around the 1.8.7 update, so this may be outdated, but jump boost is broken.

Comment: most of the answers on this site is straight from wiki(s)

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing in game and 97 seems to be the maximum effect level before the jump glitching happens.

255 would be the maximum effect level with the glitch.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing in game and in minecraft version 1.10.2 the maximum effect before the jump glitching is 127 which allows you to jump about 374 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of necroposting but:
Any level over 127 (in 1.10) will start pushing you *down*. If you stand on a slime block with a level where you can't jump, and you jump, you'll be pushed into the slime block and bounced up

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
/effect @p jump_boost 99999 255
```

you go really far up.

Comment: Did this change in an update or something? Could you say when?